# PostgreSQL database replication failure because of duplicate key violation

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, multi-master-replication, bucardo

I've configured two RHEL machines with redundancy configuration (master- master setup) with below software versions.

- Database: PostgreSQL 9.5
- Bucardo: Bucardo 5.4

Database replication goes smoothly till some point of time, After that replication stops all of sudden. I could see below kind of statements in bucardo log.

```
*KID (database_sync) Conflicts for public.interface: 4
KID (database_sync) Conflicts have been resolved
KID (database_sync) Warning! Aborting due to exception for public.interface:? Error was DBD::Pg::db pg_putcopyend failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "interface_nodeid_ifindex_unique_idx"\nDETAIL:  Key (nodeid, ifindex)=(81, 1) already exists.\nCONTEXT:  COPY interface, line 2 at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Bucardo.pm line 9879.
KID (database_sync) Kid has died, error is: DBD::Pg::db pg_putcopyend failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "interface_nodeid_ifindex_unique_idx"\nDETAIL:  Key (nodeid, ifindex)=(81, 1) already exists.\nCONTEXT:  COPY interface, line 2 at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Bucardo.pm line 9879. Line: 5041 Main DB state: ? Error: none DB database_node1 state: ? Error: none DB database_node2 state: 23505 Error: 7
DBI::db=HASH(0x2e1a708)->disconnect invalidates 9 active statement handles (either destroy statement handles or call finish on them before disconnecting) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Bucardo.pm line 2756.
DBI::db=HASH(0x2e1a828)->disconnect invalidates 9 active statement handles (either destroy statement handles or call finish on them before disconnecting) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Bucardo.pm line 2756.
KID (database_sync) Kid 22825 exiting at cleanup_kid. Sync "database_sync" public.interface Reason: DBD::Pg::db pg_putcopyend failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "interface_nodeid_ifindex_unique_idx"\nDETAIL:  Key (nodeid, ifindex)=(81, 1) already exists.\nCONTEXT:  COPY interface, line 2 at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Bucardo.pm line 9879. Line: 5041 Main DB state:
```

> ? Error: none DB database_node1 state: ? Error: none DB database_node2 state: 23505 Error: 7
>   MCP Starting check_sync_health*

Below are the steps I followed for creation of syncs.

```
bucardo add database bucardo add table all --db="$database"_node1    --herd="$database"_herd 
bucardo add sequence all --db="$database"_node1 --herd="$database"_herd 
bucardo add dbgoup "$database"_group 
bucardo add dbgroup "$database"_group    "$database"_node1:source 
bucardo add dbgroup "$database"_group    "$database"_node2:source 
bucardo add sync "$database"_sync    herd="$database_herd"_herd dbs="$database"_group    conflict_strategy=bucardo_latest onetimecopy=2 stayalive=1    kidsalive=1 autokick=1 systemctl enable bucardo.service
```

Could you please help me with your findings for the issue.
Can my sequences in my db responsible for creation of  duplicate entries in database?

Comment: Did the master experience crashes at any point? I've had similar issues (duplicate entries in a table with primary key) after the database crashed due to running out of disk space.

Comment: I need to check on crashes then, How did you resolve it ?

Comment: I had to do a dump and recreate the database from the dump, because of multiple propblems througout the DB. May be worth attempting to recreate the table in question to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

When using a multi source setup with Bucardo sequences **must not be replicated**, or conflicts will arise as you already experimented.

- Remove the sequences from the sync. I am writing from memory and not testing it, so take care

```
bucardo remove sequence all
bucardo validate all
bucardo reload
```

- Alter the sequence in each source to avoid create the same primary key in two databases. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62732508/930271) for a couple of options, like generate even, odd numbers; generate numbers like 1, 11, 21 in db1, 2, 12, 22 in db2, ...; or using UUID.